# CSS - how to make 2-column layout of 100%-height with a header of unknown height

Tags: css, layout, liquid-layout

I need to achieve subject, and really got stuck. To better describe, I've put up a picture of what I need to get:

[image]

At first I've tried to do it with `div`s, but it looks completely different in Firefox due to `width` attribute. Although my primary concern is IE8 non-standard mode (that's requirement), I wanted it to look more or less decent in Firefox.

Then I tried to do it with two-column table, and it works well in IE and somewhat well in Firefox, but for some reason if the right column content gets wider than screen, table does not accomodate and my content is cropped horizontally by the table, no scrollbar is shown.

Also, looked at the earlier posts on Stackoverflow, with `fixed` container, but it doesn't seem to work in IE8 non-standard mode.

Would be glad to hear any ideas on how this could be done.

Comment: can you provide us a lil bit code what you have done so far?

Comment: Rito, here it is: http://pastebin.com/FuhEJj13. I did initial 100% height with JS which is not good, and for some reason I'm not able to reproduce content cropping for now... I even tried to change content width with JS (to simulate real conditions -- there's grid in place of "test-wide"), but still works on this small piece and doesn't on a big page.

Comment: What happens on a real page, is that innermost `#content` `td` gets wide enough to accomodate content (~6000px), *but* `tr` (and `table`) is cropped to screen width (~1000px).

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do like this:

```
.left{
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    background:red;
    border:2px solid #000;
    top:200px;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;

}
.right{
    overflow:hidden;
    background:green;
    position:absolute;
    top:200px;
    bottom:0;
    left:204px;
    right:0;
    border:10px solid #000;
}

html, body{
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.header{
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background:yellow;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/QHTeS/

Comment: Please look at the picture: height of the header is _not known_

Comment: Doesn't work when left side have more height (content) than right.

Answer (score -1):

This should help - a very basic example.

http://jsfiddle.net/pRAgY/

Remember to adjust the width of the right container when you know the width, as the 6px border (totalling 24px) goes over the 100% width avalible.

Comment: Please look at the picture: 1) there're _two_ borders of 6px; 2) columns should be 100% high _or more_ (can grow).

Comment: Im working on this for you now, however, your objectives can be met with either example provided, with very little knowledge in CSS.

Comment: Like how (sorry, I'm not a CSS genius)? this is my _main_ concern -- to get it 100% high, same height for both columns, and allow the whole thing to grow. It's no use in having two different-sized columns.